# Ctrl + V will not work if I close the application I copied text from

Tags: kde, shortcuts, clipboard

I always have to keep an application open I copied text from to paste the text somewhere. In fact the copied text will be saved to Klipper (if Klipper is on) after it has been copied. But why cannot a simple shortcut Ctrl + V be used to paste the copied text?

OS: Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS, KDE version: 4.4.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the text is not actually "copied" anywhere. The copying application notifies the X server that it has the [**`CLIPBOARD` selection**](http://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/sec-2.html#s-2). The pasting application asks the X server which application has the `CLIPBOARD` selection, and then communicates with the application to negotiate content transfer. This obviously fails if the copying application has been closed.

Comment: I just tried this: I opened a web page in a browser (Opera), selected some text with the mouse, pressed Ctrl+C and then closed the browser. I then opened a text editor, Leafpad, and used Ctrl+V to paste what I had copied even though the source, the Opera browser, was now closed. I'm using Lubuntu 12.10. Is the requirement to keep the "source" open, a KDE thing?

Comment: Shouldn't be. Some applications may deal with the issue differently though.